# Not found response from https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/video

Tags: youtube-api

I followed the instructions on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#OAuth2_Calling_a_Google_API
to check my access to the YouTube v3 API.

I got an access_token from this:

```
curl --data "code=4/XXX.YYY" \
--data "client_id=foo123.apps.googleusercontent.com" \
--data "client_secret=YYY" \
--data "redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" \
--data "grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

which returned:

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.XYXYXY",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}
```

If I now check access with curl or in the browser

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/video?access_token=ya29.XYXYXY

I just got back "Not Found".
If I use another (phantasy) access_token or leave out the parameter the result is always the same, just "Not Found". I tried with "http" and "https".

Am I doing something wrong? Is the service just temporarily not available? Should I use v2?

Thanks for your time,
Axel.

Comment: The service seems to be working just fine. I would strongly suggest using one of the api clients that are available, -i rolled my own curl youtube library a couple of months ago and the same code that worked since then suddenly broke last week for no obvious reason. I've now switched to the php v3 client with good success so far.

Answer (score 3):

Found it myself. The documentation is misleading for me. The sample it uses

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/video?access_token=ya29.XYXYXY

doesn't say that you need further parameters. The response "Not found" from the server is not helpful. Furthermore "video" must be "videos".

A correct test would be

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?access_token=ya29.XYXYXY&id=12345678&part=snippet